# setting up my first SNS node end point, the confirmation always is an empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using node.js as my endpoint for SNS (this is my first one , correct aws terms may be missing)

The node code is pretty simple

I am using express and in my route i have

```
router.post('/bounce', 
     bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}),
     bodyParser.json(), function (req, res, next) {

  console.log("Recieving a new post ");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({success: true}));

});
```

When i subscribe via the SNS console i see the incoming post but it is always an empty object. To verify the endpoint is working i post from postman with a json object and it displays what i would expect

I have the node amazon sdk , but I do not understand where that fits in the picture

I assume i must be missing a step??

thanks for any help

Comment: I don't know exactly what `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}),` does, but is seems distinctly unnecessary here, since the request body is not a urlencoded form. It's raw JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i had to do to get what i needed

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(router);

router.post('/bounce', function(req, res){

    var chunks = [];
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        var message = JSON.parse(chunks.join(''));
        console.log(message);
    });
    res.end();

});

http.createServer( app).listen(4040, function () {
   console.log("server listening on port " + 4040);
});
```